# Convert iOS image data to corresponding bitmap object in Android

Tags: android, ios, bitmap, uiimage, nsdata

How can we convert nsdata bytes array of an image in iOS to the corresponding Bitmap bytes array in Android?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any one can help?

Comment: Help , please ?